# How to set a text label in a progress bar for each loop?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to use a `ProgressBar` to show a process and use a label to show a caption, but the label doesn't change the text for each loop.

Here's my code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
{
    ProgressBar.Increment(+1);
    string s = ProgressBar.Value.ToString() + "/" + ProgressBar.Maximum.ToString();
    lbl_progress.Text = s;
    try
    {
        //some code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please write  `lbl_progress.Update();` after assign the value in label as shown below. It will update the label values.

```
  lbl_progress.Text = s;
  lbl_progress.Update();
```

Comment: Depending on how long each task takes it may take longer to update the screen than to do the task. You could wrap the update in a IF e.g. `If iRow mod 100 = 0 Then` and you will update the screen every 100 rows.